# Solve the following equation: $x^4- 2x^2 +8x-3=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the following equation:

> $$x^4- 2x^2 +8x-3=0$$

We get 4 equations with 4 variables. But that is too difficult to solve.

My try:
Let $a,b,c,d$ be the roots of the equation.
$$a+b+c+d=0$$
$$\sum ab = -2$$
$$\sum abc = -8$$
$$abcd = -3$$
Is there any other method?

Comment: You could try first to see if it's a product of two quadratics.

Comment: how to know its possible or not?

Comment: You try it. If you succeed, it's possible. If you fail, it's not (or you screwed up).

Comment: (x^2-ax+b)(x^2-cx+d)=the eqn..??

Comment: $x^4-2x^2+8x-3=(x^2-2x+3)(x^2+2x-1)$

Comment: Try the [Rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the given equation is a product of two quadratics.
$$
x^4-2x^2+8x-3=(x^2+2x-1)(x^2-2x+3)
$$
Therefore,
$$
x=-1\pm\sqrt2
$$
or
$$
x=1\pm i\sqrt2.
$$

Comment: how have you factorized it?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I considered a product (x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)=x^4-2x^2+8x-3 and got a=2, b=-1 or a=-2, b=3

Answer (score 1):

We have : $$x^4- 2x^2 +8x-3=0\\ \Leftrightarrow (x^2-2x+3)(x^2+2x-1)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Wolframalpha will help you. Just enter `y=x^4-2x^2+8x-3=0`.  Not only will you immediately see the solutions (both exact and decimal approximation), but you also see the factorization that get's you there:

$$x^4-2x^2+8x-3 = \left(x^2-2 x+3\right) \left(x^2+2 x-1\right)$$

Of course, that factorization is trivial to verify.  Furthermore, we see a plot of the graph lending support to the numerical values of the roots.  Altogether, this is a wealth of useful information.

Comment: ...and it will teach you... _nothing_. It is not the solution that is important, but the route towards it.

Comment: @Lord_Farin I definitely suspect that the OP was looking for a "by hand" technique so I personally would probably not have pointed this user to WolframAlpha. Still, WA is a fabulous tool what can help people instantly look at many equations from all sorts of different angles.  Furthermore, your suggestion that the solution itself is not important is just absurd.

Comment: @Mark I probably would not have opposed the answer so much if it had contained some useful explanation and elaboration, like the bit you just added. With problems like this, the almost exclusive use is to have the solver learn techniques to solve this type of equation, which then get added to their repertoire. The solution is merely the aim that requires these techniques to be discovered and employed; it is not of independent interest. Even in general, the solutions to a specific polynomial equation are things one _needs_ as intermediary steps.